# alter Suggestion box for apache solr autosearch

Tags: search, ajax

I want to restrict the suggestions for Apache Solr Search with `hook_apachesolr_suggestions_alter(&$suggestions, $env_id)`. I have gone through the code and found the suggestion is prompt from `apachesolr_autocomplete_suggest_word_completion()`
called by a menu callback.

How can I override the suggestion block? I do not want to block indexing the words but just to hide them from suggestions.

Is there any hook available? Is `hook_apachesolr_suggesstions_alter(&$suggestions,$env_id)` useful in this case?

I am using `hook_apachesolr_querry_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query)`; 
I want to skip the parameters from the query. Is there any way to do  this?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any hooks for the same. The alternate solution which I got is to implement hook_menu alter.

As apachesolr uses hook_menu() I altered the menu callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7's ApacheSolr module provides the following hook:

```
function hook_apachesolr_suggestions_alter(&$suggestions, $env_id)
```

In a custom module, if you implement

```
[my-custom-module-name]_apachesolr_suggestions_alter($suggestions, $env_id)
```

You can alter the suggestions array as follows:

```
function [my-custom-module-name]_apachesolr_suggestions_alter(&$suggestions, $env_id) {
    foreach ($suggestions as $searchTerm) {
        $replacement = $searchTerm->suggestion[0];
        if ($searchTerm = 'test') {
            $replacement = 'testing';
        }
        $suggestions[$searchTerm]->suggestion[0] = $replacement;
    }
}
```

If you inspect the arrays via debugging, you'll see the following before your replacement code runs so you just need to alter what it suggests. In this case it was suggesting 'best' when searching for test, so the code above would replace 'best' with 'testing'. You'll probably want to do some optimization for error testing, but this gets you pretty far.

[image: alter suggestion]